# Вывод картинок в цикле php

Tags: php, php7

Есть код

```
<?php
$dbc = mysqli_connect('чтототам', 'ещёчтото', '', 'чтонибудьещё');
$userid = $_COOKIE['id'];

$query = "SELECT imgname FROM images WHERE userid = '$userid' ";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);



for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_rows; $i++) {
    ?>


    <img src="../uploads/<?php echo($row[$i]); ?>">

<?php
}
?>
```

На выходе получаю это
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если напишу так

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_rows; $i++) {
    ?>


    <img src="../uploads/<?php echo($row[0]); ?>">

<?php
}
?>
```

То всё отлично
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если так

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_rows; $i++) {
    ?>


    <img src="../uploads/<?php echo($row[1]); ?>">

<?php
}
?>
```

То хрен там
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что не так? Подскажите, я не особо опытный в php

Comment: если что через mysqli_fetch_row($result) тоже пробовал

Comment: сколько записей(картинок) в базе?

Comment: Ну серьёзно, вы __один раз__ вызвали fetch и ждёте что __все__ результаты появятся?

Comment: ну да, ведь fetch загоняет полученные строки в массив, разве нет?

Comment: записей всего две, но это одинаково не работает и для большего количества

Comment: всё, разобрался, не до конца понимал принцип работы этой функции